# Why does my owl carousel work on my Shopify website but not on WordPress and in Codepen?

Tags: owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to convert my shopify website to WordPress. I can't seem to get my Owl carousel to work. Does any one see what I am missing here?

Website where it works: https://obsidiangun.com/products/obsidian-pro

The code I am trying:

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Max-Huisman-the-sasster/pen/wvQxEKe)
```

I expect the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5SSW.png)